# How to log all the errors, but only if an error of a particular level ocurred?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, error-logging

I need to log all the errors (from :debug to :fatal), but only if an error of level :warn occurred.

Is it possible with rails 3 out of the box? If not, is there any logger library I can install to do this?

@ben-lee I need exactly this, look at the FingersCrossedHandler description https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog#readme

> It will accumulate log records of all levels until a record exceeds the defined severity level. At which point it delivers all records, including those of lower severity, to the handler it wraps. This means that until an error actually happens you will not see anything in your logs, but when it happens you will have the full information, including debug and info records. This provides you with all the information you need, but only when you need it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. A log level of `:warn` can only occur during runtime. The set of levels to log can only be declared ahead of time. Do you mean you want to dynamically change the log level to :all after any :warn error is logged? Or what?